# Auto generated Swift.h file keeps being not found

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode

A number of times now the auto generated Swift.h file that's required to use swift code in objective-c is not being found.

I've removed and reinstalled Xcode. Made sure all the correct boxes for it to be generated are checked and that I'm using @objc on Swift classes.

Sometimes it works fine but then there are significant periods where for an unknown reason its no longer able to find that file.

The app does build successfully, but the editor after building claims the file is missing.

The project this is being used in has multiple targets but I've made sure that the Swift.h file is using the same name in all targets.

At this point it seems there is no way to consistently have the file be available for auto completion purposes.

Any suggestions on what else to try would be appreciated as I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After seeing this issue occur randomly a number of times I discovered that I needed to build all the targets for this app. Doing that meant that the -Swift.h file that was missing was now available.

I had one target that I wasn't building as that app which was part of the project wasn't being actively worked on, but building that was the solution to the problem.